# Typescript: Extract type from generic

Tags: typescript-typings

Having a `Holder` class and a couple of instances:

```
class Holder<T> {
  listen: (val: T) => void
};
const hs = new Holder<string>();
const hn = new Holder<number>();
```

and a `HoldersObject` type which is an object containing a bunch of `Holder`s :

```
type HoldersObject = { [n: string]: Holder<any> };
```

Is there a way to correctly type a `combineHolders` function, that combines a `HoldersObject` in one `Holder` ?

```
function combineHolders<T extends HoldersObject>(h: T): Holder<{ [P in keyof T]: T[P] }>

const comb_1 = combineHolders({
  hs,
  hn,
})
// compiler yields:
// const comb_1: Holder<{
//     hs: Holder<string>;
//     hn: Holder<number>;
// }>
//
// I need:
// const comb_1: Holder<{
//     hs: string;
//     hn: number;
// }>
```

Some kind of `ExtractGeneric<T>` is needed, something like this:

```
function combineHolders<T extends HoldersObject>(h: T): 
    Holder<{ [P in keyof T]: ExtractGeneric<T[P]> }>
```

As a plus, combined holders should be able to nest (but I guess this should come for free when solved the above)

```
const comb_2 = combineHolders({
  hs,
  comb_1,
})
// compiler yields:
// const comb_2: Holder<{
//     hs: Holder<string>;
//     comb_1: Holder<any>;
// }>
// 
// I need:
// const comb_2: Holder<{
//     hs: string;
//     comb_1: {
//         hs: string;
//         hn: number;
//     };
// }>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With release of Conditional Types in TypeScript 2.8, it can be done easily. [Type inference in conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types)

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Holder%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20listen%3A%20(val%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20hs%20%3D%20new%20Holder%3Cstring%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20hn%20%3D%20new%20Holder%3Cnumber%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20HoldersObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bn%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Holder%3Cany%3E%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20combineHolders%3CT%20extends%20HoldersObject%3E(h%3A%20T)%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20Holder%3C%7B%20%5BHolderName%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BHolderName%5D%20extends%20Holder%3Cinfer%20P%3E%20%3F%20P%20%3A%20any%20%7D%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%7B%20return%20undefined%20as%20any%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20comb_1%20%3D%20combineHolders(%7B%0D%0A%20%20hs%2C%0D%0A%20%20hn%2C%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Acomb_1.listen(%7Bhs%3A%20%27%27%2C%20hn%3A%200%7D))

code:

```js
class Holder<T> {
  listen: (val: T) => void;
}
const hs = new Holder<string>();
const hn = new Holder<number>();

type HoldersObject = { [n: string]: Holder<any> };

function combineHolders<T extends HoldersObject>(
  h: T
): Holder<
  { [HolderName in keyof T]: T[HolderName] extends Holder<infer P> ? P : any }
> {
  return undefined as any;
}

const comb_1 = combineHolders({
  hs,
  hn,
});

comb_1.listen({ hs: "", hn: 0 });
```