# Extract first generic argument from type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to extract the first `Type` of the `Generic` from another `Type`. The issue that I am facing is that I have to specify the base type to extract the generic, this makes it impossible to reuse the method.

First attempt:

```
class Example<T> {}
class ExampleTwo<T> {}

type ExtractGenericArgument<T> = T extends Example<infer Generic> ? Generic : unknown;

// Works, returns string
type genericOne = ExtractGenericArgument<Example<string>>;

// Does not work, returns unknown because it cannot be matched on Example
type genericTwo = ExtractGenericArgument<ExampleTwo<string>>;
```

Is it possible to make the Generic extractor more generic? I tried the following but it gives an syntax error:

```
class Example<T> {}
class ExampleTwo<T> {}

// TS1005: '?' expected
type ExtractGenericArgument<T> = T extends (infer T)<infer Generic> ? Generic : unknown;
```

I have found some relevant examples for an `Unpacked` type on the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types). But this type only seems to work for explicit types like `Promise<T>`.

The [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951249/typescript-extract-type-from-generic) also uses `infer` to get the generic Type but has a hardcoded Type.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this interesting research endeavor!

Unfortunately I think, it is not possible currently, at least not without some work from Typescript Devs.

The problem is, as you already found out, that we need to have an exact typename written in front of `<infer Generic>`.

Here is an interesting article I found, it basically explains all usages of the 'infer' keyword which are possible (IMO this list is exhaustive with current TS version as of 202-07-27)
https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-infer-typescript/

In the meantime, we can only create copies of your type:
`type ExtractGenericArgument<T> = T extends Example<infer Generic> ? Generic : unknown;` and replace the class name `Example` with the BaseClass we need.

But in the End, it's not a deal breaker for me, my usecase does also work with your definition! :D

If you're interested, look at the `type payloadOf<eventType>` in the file
https://github.com/codemonument/event-bus-nx/blob/main/libs/event-bus-core/src/lib/event-bus/bus-event.type.ts
You should also check out the usages of this type in the adjacent files in my project
[codemonument/event-bus-nx/libs/event-bus-core project](https://github.com/codemonument/event-bus-nx/tree/main/libs/event-bus-core).

I use this generic detector type to figure out, which exact payload type was used to type the BusEvent<> class.